# how does tabIndex work when starting at a large number

Tags: html, forms

Let's say I have a complex page with a header, and many buttons.
Then lower on the page, I have a section where the order in the DOM doesn't match the actual order in which they should be focusses.

I know I can add the tabIndex attribute to make them tab-reachable in the correct order.

But how does this affect the buttons and links above the section which do not have a tabIndex?

For example:

```
<header>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
<a></a>
</header>
<div>
<button tabIndex=3 />
<button tabIndex=2 />
<button tabIndex=1 />
</div>
```

Will the links in the header be focussable before or after the buttons?

What if I start from 10 instead of 1?

Is there a way to restrict the order of tabIndex within a certain DOM element, but otherwise flow with the rest of the page?

Comment: You should not create such poor usability in the first place. As a rule of thumb, if you think you need tabindex, your site really needs a redesign.

Comment: I have good reasons for tabIndex. What I am doing is a grid layout, where the order can change easily. So I use absolute positioning. I want to update the tabIndex to follow the visual order and not the DOM order.

Comment: Also if you noticed, I am not using non-semantic tags. I'm already only using links and buttons. I just need help with ordering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Elements that support and are assigned a tabindex are navigated to first, followed by other elements. As the [W3 states](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex):

1. Those elements that support the tabindex attribute and assign a positive value to it are navigated first. Navigation proceeds from the element with the lowest tabindex value to the element with the highest value. Values need not be sequential nor must they begin with any particular value. Elements that have identical tabindex values should be navigated in the order they appear in the character stream.
2. Those elements that do not support the tabindex attribute or support it and assign it a value of "0" are navigated next. These elements are navigated in the order they appear in the character stream.
3. Elements that are disabled do not participate in the tabbing order.

Comment: So to clarify, you're saying that if I put tabIndex: 1 on all the links, and start with tabIndex 2 for the buttons then it should work in the correct order?

Comment: Yes. And this is easily testable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could put tabIndex=-1 on the links in the  section, so they wouldn't be in the tab order. That way, they would go directly to the ones with tabIndex value assigned.

Comment: I want the anchor links to be part of the tab order. I don't want them to get skipped.